# Parsing HTML Tables to Lists in Python w/o BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I was wondering if there was a way to extract data out of an HTML table and parse it into a dictionary using just HTMLParser. I'm not able to do it for some reason..

Comment: Why can't you use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: What have you tried (show some code)? What doesn't work (give an example input, what do you expect as an output, what do you get instead)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use lxml to parse a web page. http://lxml.de/

You could scrape a web page with

```
from lxml.html import parse
    site = parse('http://java.sun.com')
```

What's returned here is an lxml element tree: http://lxml.de/api.html

Then, you can use xpath to get HTML content (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/):

```
tableData = site.xpath('//table//td[@id="someTdID"]')
```

lxml is a pretty powerful library, and is widely used to scrape data. You could then feed this data into python dictionaries/lists or process it however you like.

Comment: I'd like to only use HTMLParser to do this.. Is it possible?